# ansible module add_host error: skipping: no hosts matched

Tags: windows, oracle, ansible

The Script, running on a Linux host, should call some Windows hosts holding Oracle Databases. Each Oracle Database is in DNS with its name "db-[ORACLE_SID]".
Lets say you have a database with ORACLE SID `TEST02`, it can be resolved as `db-TEST02`.
The complete script is doing some more stuff, but this example is sufficient to explain the problem.

The `db-[SID]` hostnames must be added as dynamic hosts to be able to parallelize the processing.
The problem is that oracle_databases is not passed to the new playbook. It works if I change the hosts from `windows` to `localhost`, but I need to analyze something first and get some data from the windows hosts, so this is not an option.

Here is the script:

```yaml
---
# ansible-playbook parallel.yml -e "databases=TEST01,TEST02,TEST03"

- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    ansible_connection: winrm
    ansible_port: 5985
    ansible_winrm_transport: kerberos
    ansible_winrm_kerberos_delegation: true
    
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        database: "{{ databases.split(',') }}"
    
    - name: Add databases as hosts, to parallelize the shutdown process
      add_host:
        name: "db-{{ item }}"
        groups: oracle_databases
      loop: "{{ database | list}}"
    
##### just to check, what is in oracle_databases
    - name: show the content of oracle_databases
      debug:
        msg: "{{ item }}"
      with_inventory_hostnames:
        - oracle_databases
    
- hosts: oracle_databases
  gather_facts: true
    
  tasks:
 
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "Hosts, on which the playbook is running: {{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
        verbosity: 1
```

My inventory file is just small, but there will be more windows hosts in future:

```
[adminsw1@obelix oracle_change_home]$ cat inventory
[local]
localhost

[windows]
windows68
```

And the output

```
[adminsw1@obelix oracle_change_home]$ ansible-playbook para.yml -l windows68 -e "databases=TEST01,TEST02"
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/parsing/vault/__init__.py:44: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 2 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Support for it is now deprecated in cryptography, and will be removed in a future release.
  from cryptography.exceptions import InvalidSignature
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py:89: RequestsDependencyWarning: urllib3 (1.23) or chardet (2.2.1) doesn't match a supported version!
  RequestsDependencyWarning)

PLAY [windows] *****************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ****************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [windows68]

TASK [Add databases as hosts, to parallelize the shutdown process] *************************************************************************
changed: [windows68] => (item=TEST01)
changed: [windows68] => (item=TEST02)

TASK [show the content of oracle_databases] ************************************************************************************************
ok: [windows68] => (item=db-TEST01) => {
    "msg": "db-TEST01"
}
ok: [windows68] => (item=db-TEST02) => {
    "msg": "db-TEST02"
}

PLAY [oracle_databases] ********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************************************************************************
windows68                   : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, what the problem was. The playbook is restricted to a host "windows68" and therefore can´t be run at the hosts added by the dynamic inventory.
It will work that way:

```
[adminsw1@obelix oracle_change_home]$ ansible-playbook para.yml -l windows68,oracle_databases -e "databases=TEST01,TEST02"
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible that Ansible is not parsing the updated inventory file file, or the hosts name is being malformed in as it updates the inventory.

In this scenario, you can use the **-vv** or **-vvvv** parameter in your Ansible command to get extra logging.

This will give you a complete picture into what Ansible is actually doing as it tries to parse hosts.

Comment: I know that feature in ansible, and ran it with -vvvv, but this did not reveal what the problem exactly is.

Comment: On one position ansible commited, that the host list oracle_databases had been created.
`creating host via 'add_host': hostname=db-TEST01`
`creating host via 'add_host': hostname=db-TEST02`

But then, again, the hosts are not used:
`META: ran handlers
META: ran handlers

PLAY [oracle_databases] ********************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched`

Comment: @WalterS777 after the Ansible script completes, do you see your new hosts added in the inventory?

Comment: No, the hosts are only inventored in memory, not in a file. The inventory file is not updated!